# Why was an answer to my question deleted before I could read it?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, deleted-answers

I posted a [Bounty Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1455526/how-to-solve-an-integral-with-a-gaussian-mixture-denominator) last week that only got one response.  Someone commented that the only posted answer would be taken down because it was a link to a solution.  A hour later, the **only** answer I got was taken down before I got to read it!  Is there some way I can get a look at the help someone tried to give me?

Comment: It was deleted by six different users in the [review](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/497769). The answer was basically a link to [this](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~esaff/texts/144.pdf).

Comment: Quote "The first thought that came to mind when I saw this problem was to use a Pade approximation. Here's a link to some work I think might help. http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~esaff/texts/144.pdf Cheers!  -- Frank" [transcript of review](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/497769)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi  Thank you for the explanation and link.  I still seems weird and counter-productive to me to take Answers down before the Question-er gets to read it.  That was actually helpful information and the only help I got.

Comment: @MiceElf  Thank you.  Is that Review only accessible to privileged Moderators?  Also there any way an OP can prevent Answers from being snatched away before he gets to read them?  That one Answer people took it upon themselves to delete was the only help I got.

Comment: Access requires 2000 reputation, see the bottom of [this page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit). It would be better if the answer was converted to a comment instead, but that is something only a "diamond" moderator (e.g., @Arthur Fischer) can do.

Comment: Cases like this make me think that it should be possible for the review queue to recommend that a moderator convert a deleted answer into a comment, rather than just deleting it without a trace.

Comment: Sometimes a moderator will convert an answer of mine to a comment. That has not happened in a while, I suppose i figured out how to tell when something would fit better as a comment. I still get plenty of things deleted, but that is usually when I put no mathematical content at all.

Comment: It is now a comment.